# R Reshape DATE Data

Tags: r, date, reshape

```
HAVE = data.frame('STUDENT'= c(1,2,3,4),
'1/1/2019' = c(1, NA, 8, 4),
'2/1/2019' = c(1, 3, NA, 6),    1   3       6
'1/15/2020' = c(NA, 7, NA, 10))

WANT = data.frame('STUDENT' = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
'DATE' = c(43466, 43497, 43845, 43466, 43497, 43845, 43466, 43497, 43845, 43466, 43497, 43845),
'SCORE' = c(1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 7, 8, NA, NA, 4, 6, 10))
```

I have a data file for in it the COL names are DATES and I wish to reshape from 'HAVE' to 'WANT' where the values inside are 'SCORE'

Comment: `pivot_longer(HAVE, -STUDENT, names_to = "DATE")`

Comment: @bvowe  Your `HAVE` have some typos.  Can you correct it

Comment: Try `HAVE %>% pivot_longer(cols = -STUDENT, names_to = 'DATE', values_to = 'SCORE') %>% mutate(DATE = as.numeric(mdy(DATE)))`

Comment: Feel free to set the other as duplicate